# error while extracting text from the data using replace text in NIFI

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

hi I have a text file as below

```
[2019-05-13 00:00:01] local.INFO: home.index 
{"phone":"959452735778","ua":"MMDataMall/11002 CFNetwork/976 
 Darwin/18.2.0"}
```

Now I need to extract data as below

```
2019-05-13 00:00:01,959452735778,MMDataMall/11002 CFNetwork/976 
 Darwin/18.2.0
```

I am using text replacetext processor but I am getting empty document

my search value:- `(.+?)\s+:local INFO.*phone\s+(\[.*\])\s+(?=,).*ua\s+(\[.*\])\s+(?=,)$`

my replacementvalue:- `$1 ,$2,$3`

replacetext Screenshot
[image]

can any one help me with this

Comment: i can't understand why do you have `${att:replaceAll(...` in search value. and you must have replacement value.

Comment: sorry I have entered wrong values now I have edited please check @daggett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

`\[(.*)\][\s\S]*\{\S+?:"(\d+)\S+:"([\s\S]*)"}`

then replace with

`$1,$2,$3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uVpSPt/1)

1. The first group captures the text between `[` and `]`.
2. The second group skips everything until it finds the first `:"` combination, and then captures the phone number.
3. The third group finds the next `:"` combination and then captures everything until the closing `"`.

Answer (score 1):

This expression captures three groups which you can bind it with commas and might return your desired output:

```
 \[(.*)\][\s\S]*?phone":"(.*)?","[a-z]+":"([\s\S]*?)"}
```

I'm not however so sure about that if it would work in NIFI. You can also simply add or reduce the boundaries if you wish.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oJrRqp/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /\[(.*)\][\s\S]*?phone":"(.*)?","[a-z]+":"([\s\S]*?)"}/gm;
const str = `[2019-05-13 00:00:01] local.INFO: home.index 
{"phone":"959452735778","ua":"MMDataMall/11002 CFNetwork/976 
 Darwin/18.2.0"}`;
const subst = `$1,$2,$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```